# How to parse values from text in a cell and place values into other cells

Tags: vba, parsing, excel

I have a cell with the below text in column N2.

`71sdfsdf             2230400DATE of join        1997-06-03PROGRAMME : ACCES PLUSNew Value                  534.55Right value                 534.55Clear Value                  308.50`

I need the number after `New Value` that is 534.55 in this case to be saved in column O2, The value next to `Right Value` that is 534.55 again in column P2 and if `Clear Value` is present then the value next to it that is 308.50 to be saved in Q2.

`Clear value` won't always be included.

Can we write a macro for this? I have used `InStr` to get the value if present in the cell but I am not aware how the cursor position in macro works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using the InStr function then all you have to do is plop the value you extracted into the cell you want:

```
Public Sub YourMethod()

    Dim s As String
    s = "71sdfsdf 2230400DATE of join 1997-06-03PROGRAMME : ACCES PLUSNew Value 534.55Right value 534.56Clear Value 308.50"

    Const NEW_VALUE = "New Value"
    Const RIGHT_VALUE = "Right value"
    Const CLEAR_VALUE = "Clear Value"

    Dim posNewValue As Integer
    posNewValue = InStr(1, s, NEW_VALUE, VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare)

    Dim posRightValue As Integer
    posRightValue = InStr(posNewValue, s, RIGHT_VALUE, VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare)

    Dim posClearValue As Integer
    posClearValue = InStr(posRightValue, s, CLEAR_VALUE, VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare)

    Dim newValue As String
    posNewValue = posNewValue + Len(NEW_VALUE)
    newValue = Mid$(s, posNewValue, posRightValue - posNewValue)

    Dim rightValue As String
    Dim clearValue As String
    posRightValue = posRightValue + Len(RIGHT_VALUE)
    If posClearValue > 0 Then
        rightValue = Mid$(s, posRightValue, posClearValue - posRightValue)
        posClearValue = posClearValue + Len(CLEAR_VALUE)
        clearValue = Mid$(s, posClearValue)
    Else
        rightValue = Mid$(s, posRightValue)
    End If

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2").Value = newValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P2").Value = rightValue
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q2").Value = clearValue


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If lenght of numbers is consant you can use something like this:

```
For i = MyStart To MyLimit 'rows of the range of interest
    If InStr(1, "New Value ", Range("N" & i).Value) <> 0 Then _
        Range("O" & i).Value = Mid(Range("N" & i).Value, InStr(1, "New Value ", Range("N" & i).Value), 6)
    If InStr(1, "Right Value ", Range("N" & i).Value) <> 0 Then _
        Range("P" & i).Value = Mid(Range("N" & i).Value, InStr(1, "Right Value ", Range("N" & i).Value), 6)
    If InStr(1, "Clear Value ", Range("N" & i).Value) <> 0 Then _
        Range("Q" & i).Value = Mid(Range("N" & i).Value, InStr(1, "Clear Value ", Range("N" & i).Value), 6)
Next i
```

Pay attention to the presence or not of spaces (I suppose they were present)

Comment: Thanks Genepos the length of the number is not constant